# Установка uwsgi, unrecognized option '--wsgi-file'

Tags: python, django

```
$alexey@alexey:~/Projects/flower_shop$ uwsgi --http-socket :8000 --wsgi-file start.py
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--wsgi-file'
getopt_long() error
```

Установка на ubuntu, вот такая ошибка: **uwsgi: unrecognized option '--wsgi-file'**

Не могу найти решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, установка версий uwsgi не **позже 1.4.10** поможет.